# Actualizar DIV sin recargar pagina al recibir dato de Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

En un div, con CSS, estoy intentando actualizar su color de fondo con un cambio en una base de datos en Firebase. Dicha actualización solo la veo si doy refresh en el navegador. Quisiera que se actualice el div correspondiente desde que se realiza el cambio en Firebase. Adjunto códigos:

Acá realizo los cambios de clase:

```
function changeColor(colorChange) {
if ((colorChange == 1) || (colorChange == 11)){
    document.getElementById('Asiento7').classList.remove('blink','flash');
    document.getElementById('Asiento7').classList.add('Busy');
}
```

Los cambios anteriores son realizados leyendo desde la base de datos:

```
var databaseEstado = firebase.database().ref('CubiculosIndividuales/Asiento1/status');
    databaseEstado.once("value", function(snap){
    status = snap.val();
    changeColor(status);
});
```

Comment: el problema es que no te llama a la funciòn changeColor?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav
El problema es que para ver el cambio que realiza dicha función, tengo que actualizar la pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que usas el método `once` que se ejecuta una sola vez, cuando debes usar el método `on`, que se ejecuta cada vez que hay un cambio en la base de datos:

```
var databaseEstado = firebase.database().ref('CubiculosIndividuales/Asiento1/status');
databaseEstado.on("value", function(snap){
    status = snap.val();
    changeColor(status);
});
```

[Aquí puedes leer la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=es-419).